# Measuring Incoming Gas Pressure to Stove

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, gas, natural-gas, range

I have a new BlueStar Platinum range that I'm trying to hook up.  I am wanting to make sure everything is connected per their instructions.  They mention the following regarding the incoming gas line:

- Incoming gas pressure should be checked with a manometer. The correct manifold pressure for natural gas is 5.0” wc.  Incoming line pressure upstream of the appliance should be 1.0” wc greater than the operating manifold pressure.

I currently have a 3/4" pipe stubbed out behind the stove with a shut-off valve.  I would think testing the pressure would be as easy as connecting a gauge to this fitting and then opening the valve but I can't seem to find evidence of this being the case.  It seems like most of these manometers are designed to connect to appliances themselves or something.

If anyone knows how I can test this it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The standard gas pressure supplied to houses is 7" WC. Go to the website of your gas supplier and find out what they supply.

If you want to test this yourself, just connect the manometer to the tap and see what you have. This will be a static test and the pressure could drop when the gas is flowing, but probably it won't drop significantly. It is marginally better to use a Tee and test the pressure under flow, but for a minimal verification a static test is sufficient

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!  I'm guessing they make something that screws into the stubbed out fitting and then converts to a nipple the manometer's hose attaches to?

Comment: The pressures are so low that it is possible that there is a press fit connection that either fits inside the pipe (or valve) or makes a seal when it is pressed against the end of the pipe or valve. All you need is a temporary connection to verify that the pressure is about 5" to 7" WC. Honestly I think most people would assume that they have standard low pressure gas and just connect the new gas range without even using the manometer.

Comment: I'm not sure which range the OP has, but I looked up a 48" Bluestar Platinum range ($11,000) and it has 8 burners (4 are >= 22,000 BTU). If all burners and ovens are on, it'll be using 188,000 BTU, which is more than many furnaces. For a range of that price and capacity, it's probably worth doing the flow test under typical operating conditions to make sure it's not going to be constrained by the gas supply. If it's a home kitchen where he'll rarely use more than a few burners at once, then it probably doesn't matter, but if he wants to use them all, it might be.

Comment: Note that many places are switching from 7" WC pressure to 2 PSIG (Pounds per Square Inch Gauge), which is almost 8x higher pressure (equivalent to about 55" WC). Then each appliance must have a regulator to drop the pressure to the 7" WC that it expects. Details [here](http://www.ashireporter.org/HomeInspection/Articles/How-the-Bottom-Line-is-Changing-Residential-Gas-Systems/2050).